# Libre office Draw How to change font color of pdf form fillable text box

Tags: forms, pdf, libreoffice

I hope i'm just missing something small, but i am unable to change the default font color of a form fillable text box in libreoffice Draw. My end goal is to convert a regular PDF to one that is form fillable. What keeps happening is i get a default black form fillable text box with white text. What i want is a white/transparent text box with black text.

I have tried to edit the properties of the text and text box under control properties > General I can set the font, font size and background color of the text box but i can't seem to find the option to set the font color. When I export the document to PDF File > export as PDF and I tick off create PDF form What I get is a white text box on my pdf (good) When I click to fill it out it turns black with white text. (Bad). When I click away i get white text on a white textbox background so you are unable to read it.

After perusing the forms for a bit, I am unable to find a solution so i'm hoping someone here can help

I can provide pictures if needed

I have also tried setting all the styles to black font color ranter than default font color. Running LibreOffice V 7.0.1.2 on Ubuntu V 20.04

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug of LibreOffice.

You can check https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106810